How to add gradient to text placeholder in React-Native TextInput
I want to add linear gradient color #F79294 and #A245B8 to placeholder of this Textarea. Then I want the color of text that user input has linear gradient: #ED8A99 and #A044B8.
<Textarea
                                        containerStyle={styles.textareaContainer}
                                        onChangeText={(e: any) => onChangeInput(e)}
                                        underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
                                        value={textInput}
                                        placeholder={t('Write your text here')}
                                        placeholderTextColor={'#A044B8'}
                                        style={{
                                            color: '#ED8A99',
                                            fontWeight: '700',
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            lineHeight: 20,
                                            flex: 1,
                                            textAlignVertical: 'top',
                                            paddingBottom: 0,
                                            paddingTop: 0,
                                        }}
                                    />

